# window pythonw is openning by itself

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to draw a very simple graph (using pygraph). In my code I use a pushbutton to plot some data on the main window. It works quite well, but I stil have one small issue. When I click in the button, the graph appears well, but there is also a window popping (pythonw) with nothing on it. Any idea why ? Is there a way to do it without this popping window ?

```py
    def traceprofil(self):
        data = np.ones(24)
        m = pg.plot(data)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(m, 1 , 8 , 3, 3 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pyqtgraph.plot()` creates a window with a `plotWidget` inside. This window is the extra window you see. To just create a `plotWidget` and plot the data you could try this instead:

```
    def traceprofil(self):
        data = np.ones(24)
        m = pg.PlotWidget(self)
        m.getPlotItem().plot(data)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(m, 1 , 8 , 3, 3 )
```